el comando w -his no me funciona linux
Cuando introduzco el comando w -his "me sale violación de segmento ('core' generado)"
y no entiendo el porqué y he probado de todo actualizar el paquete, algunas me dicen que solo debo reiniciar, pero nada de eso me ha funcionado.
¿Qué debo hacer para solucionar el error?

El comando w no tiene parámetro i. Prueba con w -hs o w -h -s. https://linux.die.net/man/1/w

@Mateo Según este enlace sí que lo tiene:  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/w.1.html

La opción -i de w efectivamente existe, solo que se añadió en procps-ng-3.3.4. De eso hace más de una década, aún así no debería generar un SF, que por otra parte puede ser por mil cosas. Mieles S. ¿que versión de ubuntu y del paquete estás usando exactamente? Creo que puede ser el problema corregido con este commit upstream: https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/commit/79042e07, si lo es, puede que simplemente no esté aún disponible en Ubuntu. Si no te es imprescindible, puedes no usar -s (short) mientras tanto.
